# Refer to a File by NTFS Object Identifier (GUID) in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, file, guid

I would like to know how, using VB.NET, to refer to a file by it's NTFS Object Identifier (GUID, or formally "16-byte buffer").

I found and studied [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110228-00/?p=11363) from Raymond Chen on MS DevBlogs, but the code he gives is written in C, and unfortunately I'm not sharp enough to know how to translate it into VB.NET. The article seems to suggest that you can invoke built-in Windows functions to fetch and/or assign a file GUID, but I could really use some help getting this out of C and into .NET. (Namely, I'm struggling to discover which references to include to mimic those header files he's included...)

Comment: Are you trying to create a file name with a guid?  Or read a file that is named with a guid?

Comment: Both, potentially. I would like to create a small set of files, each of which is given a filesystem GUID, and update/remove those files at a later date but using the GUID to locate them. (Note: not trying to NAME the file with a GUID... trying to assign files a GUID in the "undercarriage" of the filesystem like in the article.)

Comment: `Dim filename As String = $"c:\temp\{Guid.NewGuid}.txt"`

Comment: This is not at all what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to set the *Object Identifier* for the file, which is not the filename.

Comment: Found a cheap way that I can read/set/remove file OID's using `fsutil.exe objectID` and redirecting standard output, but that doesn't help with *finding* a file by its OID sans filename and path, which is the ultimate point.